# Calculate the closed form of $\frac{\sqrt[5]{5}}{\sqrt[3]{3}}\cdot \frac{\sqrt[9]{9}}{\sqrt[7]{7}}\cdot \frac{\sqrt[13]{13}}{\sqrt[11]{11}}\cdot ...$

Tags: calculus, power-series

Calculate in closed form of:
$$\frac{\sqrt[5]{5}}{\sqrt[3]{3}}\cdot \frac{\sqrt[9]{9}}{\sqrt[7]{7}}\cdot \frac{\sqrt[13]{13}}{\sqrt[11]{11}}\cdot ...$$

it has closed form. My solution uses the Kummer formula, and I would like to know if someone is encouraged to give a different solution
I obtain $\exp \left( -\frac{\pi \gamma }{4} \right)\cdot \left( \frac{\Gamma \left( \frac{1}{4} \right)}{\sqrt[4]{4\pi ^{3}}} \right)^{\pi }$

Comment: Is there a reason to think there is a closed form?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Yes, it has closed form with gamma function, euler mascheroni, logarithm and pi. My solution uses the kummer formula

Comment: @whitexlotus you should add your solution.

Comment: $\frac{\sqrt[5]{5}}{\sqrt[3]{3}}\cdot \frac{\sqrt[9]{9}}{\sqrt[7]{7}}\cdot \frac{\sqrt[13]{13}}{\sqrt[11]{11}}\cdot ...=\exp \left( -\frac{\pi \gamma }{4} \right)\cdot \left( \frac{\Gamma \left( \frac{1}{4} \right)}{\sqrt[4]{4\pi ^{3}}} \right)^{\pi }$
You can see my solution in the following link
mathematica.gr/forum/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=58309

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The given infinite product equals

$$ P=\exp\sum_{n\geq 1}\left(\frac{\log(4n+1)}{4n+1}-\frac{\log(4n-1)}{4n-1}\right)=\exp\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\chi(n)\log(n)}{n}. $$
with $\chi$ being the non-principal [Dirichlet's character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_character) $\!\!\pmod{4}$.
In compact form, $P=\exp\left(-L'(\chi,1)\right)$. By Frullani's Theorem $\log(n)=\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{e^{-x}-e^{-nx}}{x}\,dx$, hence:

$$ P=\exp\left(-L'(\chi,1)\right) = \exp\int_{0}^{+\infty}\left(\frac{\pi}{4}e^{-x}-\arctan e^{-x}\right)\frac{dx}{x} $$
By considering the Taylor series of $\frac{\pi(1-z)}{4}-\arctan(1-z)$ around the origin we may easily derive the approximation $\color{blue}{P\approx 0.82}$. The previous integral representation recalls Binet's [second $\log\Gamma$ formula](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BinetsLogGammaFormulas.html). Indeed, by the Malmsten-Kummer Fourier series, for any $z\in(0,1)$ we have:

$$ \log\Gamma(z) = \left(\tfrac12 - z\right)(\gamma + \log 2) + (1 - z)\ln\pi
- \frac12\log\sin\pi z  + \frac{1}{\pi}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sin 2\pi n z \cdot\log n} n$$

hence an explicit representation for $P$ can be simply found by plugging in $z=\frac{1}{4}$:

$$\boxed{ P = \color{blue}{\left(\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^4}{4\pi^3 e^{\gamma}}\right)^{\frac{\pi}{4}}}\approx 0.82456334.}$$

Comment: I obtain $$\exp \left( -\frac{\pi \gamma }{4} \right)\cdot \left( \frac{\Gamma \left( \frac{1}{4} \right)}{\sqrt[4]{4\pi ^{3}}} \right)^{\pi }$$ very nice you proof

Comment: @whitexlotus: I agree, it is the same thing.

Comment: Jack, here my solution http://www.mathematica.gr/forum/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=58309

Comment: @whitexlotus: nice. The interesting consequence (at least for me) is an explicit evaluation of $L'(\chi,1)$ for some simple non-principal characters.

Answer (score 1):

For every $n\ge 3$ we have $$\sqrt[n]{n}>\sqrt[n+2]{n+2}$$ because it is equivalent to $n^2>(1+\frac{2}{n})^n$ which is true by comparison to the RHS limit: $n^2>e^2>(1+\frac{2}{n})^n$.

This proves that every term of your product is less then 1.

Obviously is also positive.

Is it enough to prove that the product equals 0?

Comment: No. ${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: It's $0.824563..$

Comment: For a concrete counterexample: $\prod_{n=2}^\infty \frac{n^2-1}{n^2} = \frac{1}{\pi}$.

Comment: Nope, this doesn't prove the product is zero.

Comment: Might help to take the logarithm of your conjecture: if $a_n < 0$ for all $n$, does that imply $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ diverges to $-\infty$?

Comment: @platty $$\frac{n^2-1}{n^2}=\dfrac{\frac{n+1}{n}}{\frac{n}{n-1}}$$ so that product telescopes and you get $\frac{1}{2}$, not $\frac{1}{\pi}$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews my bad, forgot the factor of 2 -.-

Comment: @ThomasAndrews replacing $n$ by $2n$ should [work](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallis_product).

Comment: @DanielSchepler No I took the integral and it's about $-0.172918$ exponentiating gives $0.841207$ almost the value of Rozenberg, which is the value I found first. But no closed form... if Mathematica can't, I don't even try :)

Comment: @Raffaele: there is a closed form, but it is not very nice, see below.