# Relation between lemniscate constant and hyperbolic tangent.

Tags: gamma-function, infinite-product, hyperbolic-functions

Recently I came across this identity:
$$
\prod _{n=1}^{{\infty }}\:\tanh \:\left(\frac{\pi n}{2}\right)=\frac{\Gamma \left(\frac{1}{4}\right)}{\sqrt[4]{8\pi ^3}}
$$
The question is: how to prove this identity? Is there any theorem that can help prove this relation?

Comment: A strange connection with the formula [there](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2385865)

Comment: An almost identical question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/363004). See as well [this](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h293877p1589147.)

Answer (score 2):

Nice one. Let us start as follows.
$$
\prod _{n=1}^{{\infty }}\:\tanh \:\left(\frac{\pi n}{2}\right)=\left.\prod _{n=1}^{{\infty }}\frac{1-q^n}{1+q^n}\right|_{q=e^{-\pi}}.
$$
You may now observe (term by term) that the latter product actually reads as follows
$$
\prod _{n=1}^{{\infty }}\frac{1-q^n}{1+q^n} = 1-2q+2q^4 + ... = 1+2\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(-1)^k q^{k^2}=\vartheta_4(0,q)
$$ 
where the last equality follows directly from the definition of Jacobi theta function $\vartheta_4 (z,q)$. Now, your identity follows from known results for $\vartheta_4(0,q)$. First, let us use [connection to Dedekind eta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theta_function#Relations_to_Dedekind_eta_function):
$$\vartheta_4(0,q=e^{\pi i\tau})=\frac{\eta^2(\tau/2)}{\eta(\tau)},$$
where we have $\tau=i$. The final step is to use [special values of Dedekind eta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind_eta_function#Special_values) to obtain your identity.

Comment: Thank you for your solution! Do you know how special values of theta function are derived,is there a proof?

Comment: Jean Marie posted several links above, it turns out that this identity is popular.